# How can I shape navigation bar in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Is it possible to shape the navigation bar in iOS like shown in the image below? I have multiple screen like this image. I don't want to add image in all view. I want to common things to do that.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]I have a project with same your problem, but them gradient color is vertical alignment.
You can refer my code:

```
class _BackgroundView: UIView {

    var radius: CGFloat = 28 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    var startColor = UIColor(red: 51/255, green: 115/255, blue: 199/255, alpha: 1)
    var endColor = UIColor(red: 46/255, green: 187/255, blue: 228/255, alpha: 1)

    var barHeight: CGFloat = 44

    @available(iOS 11.0, *)
    override func safeAreaInsetsDidChange() {
        super.safeAreaInsetsDidChange()
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
            return
        }
        context.saveGState()

        context.clear(rect)

        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

        guard let startColorComponents = startColor.cgColor.components else {
            return
        }
        guard let endColorComponents = endColor.cgColor.components else {
            return
        }

        let colorComponents: [CGFloat] = [startColorComponents[0], startColorComponents[1], startColorComponents[2], startColorComponents[3], endColorComponents[0], endColorComponents[1], endColorComponents[2], endColorComponents[3]]

        let locations:[CGFloat] = [0.0, 1.0]

        guard let gradient = CGGradient(colorSpace: colorSpace,colorComponents: colorComponents,locations: locations,count: 2) else { return }

        let startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        var endPoint: CGPoint
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            endPoint = CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: safeAreaInsets.top + barHeight + radius)
        } else {
            endPoint = CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height + barHeight + radius)
        }

        context.saveGState()
        context.addRect(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: rect.width, height: endPoint.y))
        context.clip()
        context.drawLinearGradient(gradient, start: startPoint, end: endPoint, options: CGGradientDrawingOptions(rawValue: UInt32(0)))
        context.restoreGState()

        let y: CGFloat
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            y = safeAreaInsets.top + barHeight
        } else {
            y = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height + barHeight
        }
        let roundRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: rect.width, height: rect.height - y)
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: roundRect, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(w: radius, h: radius))
        UIColor.white.setFill()
        path.fill()
        context.addPath(path.cgPath)

        context.restoreGState()
    }

}
```

Comment: how can i use this code?

Comment: @Maulikshah you should hide navigationBar of navigationController, override loadView function, then set view = _BackgroundView()

Comment: But I want navigationbar Becuase every View have title and back button

Comment: You can add back button and title by code, I add `barHeight` property for your items space

Comment: all views, you can create a `BaseViewController` for all your controller, that using a shape navigation.

Comment: https://github.com/tiennv157/GradientNavigation

Comment: good work.. ....